Gröbner bases computation for not fully specified polynomials
Gröbner bases computation works on several computer systems. I have this question. Is it possible to compute (in any of the systems, eventually in which?) Gröbner basis for integer polynomials, in which some (not all) coefficients are given formally, so just by letters representing integer coefficients? Or does every task have to be completely specific in principle?

A recent answer I gave which might give some ideas along those lines: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710589/declaring-constants-in-sagemath/4710853#4710853
